# Deobfuscating Unknown C# obfuscator?

Tags: deobfuscation, .net, c#

**Hello,**

I am having an exe file that I am trying to deobfuscate and debug using dnspy. The exe file was written in C# and obfuscated with unknown deobfuscate according to de4dot! I tried to all my known methods to procced but still I was not able to fully deobfusticated it.

---

## Analysing the File

### - Exeinfo PE

**I tried to analysie the file with exeinfope to check which obfustactor was used but I only got [obfus/crypted].**

Microsoft Visual C# / Basic.NET / MS Visual Basic 2005 [ Obfus/Crypted- StrongName set ]  - EP Token : 06000080 ,
Overlay : 403900... Nothing discovered

[image]

### - Dnspy

Opening the file in dnspy but the code wasn't readable, especially the methods and the functions name are in unicode form.

[image]

---

## My Attempts:

1. Tried to deobfustace the file with de4dot, but I get "Detected Unknown Obfuscator" followed by an error.
2. Tried a modded version of de4dot, and I was able to deobfustacte the exe,but all functions shown as "delegate". The exe file was detected as "Unkown Obfustactor" as well, but managed to cleaned it.
   [image]
3. Tried to debug the cleaned verison but when I start dnspy I get an exception (System.NullReferenceException)
   [image]

---

## My Questions:

1. Which obfustactor was used ?
2. Why all functions are defined as "delgate"?
3. Why did I get the null exception while debugging

Thanks...

---

## UPDATE 20/08/2020

While looking through the code, I found that all "delegate" calls are referred to a function which takes an intger but I couldn't find any obvious return from this function, what I do think it returns the function and method name but... HOW!!
[image]

[image]

Comment: I do not know which one specifically, but perhaps one of the deobfuscators aside from de4dot can help? - https://github.com/NotPrab/.NET-Deobfuscator

Comment: Thanks, but still I haven't accomplished anything with the list, but it's a really good list to keep.. I appreciate it.

Comment: I have the same problem, I have tried many tools, but after deobfuscation, the program doesn't work

Comment: This looks like a crypto obfuscator assembly, get in touch with me and i might be able to run a tool i developed to deob this kind of obfuscated code.

Comment: Can you take a TTD trace of the app launching? https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/time-travel-debugging-overview This could be used to analyze what is going on, but it may or may not work, and needs some familiarity with windbg and the sos/sosex extensions to use effectively

Comment: Welcome to RE.SE. This is a stack exchange site and not a forum - This section should only be used to post answers. I'm marking this post as "Not an Answer".